# Modeling web scraper

Tags: object-oriented, solid, web-scraping

I'm working on a small application that is supposed to scrape/parse a few website and I'm wondering which would be the best way to achieve this (keeping DRY/SOLID in mind).

Here's some pseudocode:

```
class ScraperScheduler
  def perform
    SraperWorker.perform_async(ParserTypeOne.new)
    SraperWorker.perform_async(ParserTypeTwo.new)
    SraperWorker.perform_async(ParserTypeThree.new)
    SraperWorker.perform_async(ParserTypeFour.new)
  end
end

class ScraperWorker
  def initialize(scraper)
    @scraper = scraper
  end

  def perform
    html = RestClient.get(@scraper.url)
    @scraper.perform_async(html)
  end
end

class ParserTypeOne 
  def perform(html)
    #parse page with nokogiri
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

    parserd_objects.each do |o|
      PersistToDB.perform(o)
    end
  end
end

class PersistToDB
  def perform(o)
    # split o into several ActiveRecord objects
    # check if unique and save to db
  end
end
```

The `ScraperScheduler` class is basically just a cronjob that will be called with [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) once a day. The perform methods are there so I can basically make sidkiq jobs out of everything, but I don't think this is necessary for each one of those classes. Some questions/concerns I have:

1. ScraperWorker basically only performs the HTTP request. Yet in my example it knows about the `url` and `perform_async` properties of the Parser. Any way to do this in a more "loosely coupled" way?
2. The `ParserTypeOne` job should be just extracting the data from the HTML with nokogiri. Is it too closely coupled to PersistToDB? How cann I call PersistToDB differently?
3. Any other suggestions?

I know this would work fine I'm just interested in a few ideas on how to improve this. Suggestions?

Comment: How would you expect a scraper to perform an HTTP request unless it knows the URL?

Answer (score -1):

ad1 Consider moving the http get call from ScrapperWorker to Parser, so the URL will be known only to Parser.

ad2 You can hide PersistToDB behind some interface and than inject this dependency by class constructor.

ad3 In ScrapperScheduler class you can move types configuration to some external configuration file like XML, than with some change in configuration you don't have to recompile your application.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by ad2?

Comment: See dependency injection pattern.

Comment: I understand what you mean by DI, but inject it to which class? If I follow your ad1 than ScraperWorker becomes unnecessary. Should I inject the PersistToDB directly to the Parser?